# JSON response is not working after upgrade to struts2.5.8

Tags: json, ajax, struts2

before I upgrade the struts from 2.3.x to 2.5.8, the JSON can return data to me,but now return JSON value is empty in struts2.5.8, whatever what type i have put. here is my code:

**TestController.java**

```
public class TestingController implements ModelDriven<Object> {
  private ArrayList<Test> testList = null;
  public ArrayList<Test> getTestList() { return testList;}

  public String tableData() {
    jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    testList = getTestListBySomething();
    if(testList!=null && testList.size()>0){
      jsonMap.put("test", testList);
    }

  }
```

also my **struts.xml**:

```
   <package name="default" namespace="" extends="rest-default,struts-default" strict-method-invocation="false">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>
   </package>
```

I have checked that the testList have data and size, but in the response on ajax , it show:

```
{"test":""}
```

What wrong of my coding?

Comment: I don't know how the **struts2-rest-plugin** works, but the `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult` is from the **struts2-json-plugin**. Is it still in your project ? Does it have the right version ?

Comment: Hi Andrea, it still in project and both upgrade to 2.5.8

Comment: Please, show the action configuration. Also remember that it's better to define variables with the interface (List), not the implementation (ArrayList)

Comment: Here is the action configuration:
@Namespace("/test")
@Results({
  @Result(name="json", type="json", params = {"root", "jsonMap"})
 })

Comment: What have you changed, along with the libraries versions, when moving from 2.3 to 2.5 ?

Comment: I have also change the web.xml filter from         <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
to         <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

Answer (score 0):

```
In your strust xml add below parameter.    


    <param name="root">#action</param>

EX :

<result-types>
   <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            <param name="root">#action</param>
            <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
            <param name="excludeProperties">errors</param>
   </result-type>
 </result-types>
```